# For my data, why can tree-based learning algorithms have accuracies only about 50%?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

For my data, I have tried several tree-based algorithms with grid search, such as XGBoostClassifier, RandomForestClassifier, but the accuracies are only about 50%.

Then I tried SVC, the testing accuracy can up to 80% in the grid search.

Is there any method(visualization is preferred) can help us to tell the reasons behind?

Comment: It is impossible to tell for sure without further details. It sounds like SVC might perform better because you optimize the hyperparameters for the particular data set (grid search), whereas you do not perform hyperparameter optimization for the Random Forests?

Comment: @kazemakase
Yes, I have performed hyperparameter optimization for both tree-based and SVMs algorithms via grid search, however, the cv accuracies did not improve more than 50% in all the cases of tree-based algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, SVMs are great for relatively small data sets with fewer outliers. Random forests require more data but in my experience tend to be a pretty robust model. In practice, the decision which classifier to choose really depends on your dataset and the general complexity of the problem which I'm not sure of exactly in your case.
    I should mention another potential deviation can be the parameters to tune. In a random forest tree there are limited parameters to tune (maybe except for the number of trees; typically, the more trees we have the better). Whereas for SVMs you have to choose the "right" kernel, regularization penalties, the slack variable, etc. which is another reason that usually Random Forest "out of the box" tend to perform better.

If it comes to predictive performance, there are cases where SVMs do better than random forests and vice versa. See paper below.

```
Caruana, Rich, and Alexandru Niculescu-Mizil. "An empirical comparison of supervised learning algorithms." Proceedings of the 23rd international conference on Machine learning. ACM, 2006.
```